# Redirecionamento para Link Externo

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic

Boa tarde.

Quando abro uma página externa a partir de um link no meu aplicativo ionic, ela é renderizada no navegador comum ou na própria webview do aplicativo?

Caso seja renderizada na própria webview, como eu poderia fazer com que ela abrisse o navegador ou algo parecido?

Answer (score 2):

Para abrir no navegador você pode usar o plugin [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). Neste link tem algumas referencias de como usar. Pode fazer desta forma:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.site.com', '_system');">www.site.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você não tiver o plugin [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) instalado, a página externa é aberta na própria webview do app.

O inAppBrowser substitui o windows open e você pode escolher abrir em outro webview (_blank) ou no navegador do sistema (_system)